# Extending ngClick for adding additional function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello all there is any way to extend the inbuilt directive?

This is what I want to do.

For example my directive template is :

```
    <div ng-click="condition && handleClick()" ng-transclude></div>
```

here condition is whether to perform the click to the div or not so when I reused the directive and make it nested I end-up like this.

note : the condition in my directive will not change dynamically this is just one time value.

```
    <div ng-click="condition && handleClick()">
        <div ng-click="condition && handleClick()">
            <div ng-click="condition && handleClick()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So now the problem is if ng-click is added to the div angular binds the touchstart or click and others to the div, I want to avoid this bindings, due to this bindings many unnecessary events are added to the div which is not needed.

Now I want to extend the ng-click directive and need to add the condition check before binding the events with the element, if the condition is false I will not bind the event else if it true I will bind the event.

For fixing this I can write my own directive ng-click-condition and perform same operation as ng-click but with condition check but if I do this I will be lead to code duplication and maintainability issue, so I am finding some way to reuse the in-built directive.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should package all this logic inside the directive.

Set the scope of the directive to scope: {}  (scope: true, may work as well.  Just as long as each directive gets it's own scope)

Inside the link function of your directive:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  if (condition) {
    //do something awesome
  }
})
```

Or if you want to avoid the bindings unless the condition is met, just reverse the binding.  But I would still put it in the directive:

```
if (some condition) {
  element.bind('click', function() {
    //do something awesome
  })
}
```

Binding click and touchstart:
[How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

EDIT:
Still not quite sold on needing to extend ng-click.  How about just conditionally adding ng-click?

[Dynamically add angular attributes to an element from a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987784/dynamically-add-angular-attributes-to-an-element-from-a-directive)

[Angular directive how to add an attribute to the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687925/angular-directive-how-to-add-an-attribute-to-the-element)

Comment: thanks for your answer, as you mentioned my all of my directives have own scope, i don't want to do as you mentioned in your answer because i don't want to bind the events myself because ng-click has good event control on touchscreen and non touch screen, so i want to reuse the ng-click but i don't want to duplicate the code.

Comment: my application is for both touch screen and non touch screen, ng-click handles both the condition and handles more then this like different browser compatibility and ghost click etc, so i want to use the ng-click with this condition.

Comment: Why wouldn't conditionally adding the ng-click to the element work?